# Why my object save only last data

Tags: javascript, object, push

I'm creating two objects, `struct_one` and the auxiliary `struct_two` for primary save a data.
After adding data with the help of `.push`. Everything data from the `struct_one` array, have a last the data.

```js
var struct_one =  {  comments:[{comment:String}]  };
var struct_two = {comment:String};

function taskElementWork() {

  this. createBlockSaveNew = function() {
    struct_two.comment = 1 + "RED";
    struct_one.comments.push(struct_two); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[1].comment); // = 1RED
    struct_two.comment = 2 + "RED";
    struct_one.comments.push(struct_two); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[2].comment); // = 2RED
    struct_two.comment = 3 + "RED";
    struct_one.comments.push(struct_two); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[3].comment); // = 3RED

    console.log(struct_one.comments[1].comment); // = 3RED   -> Why!  
  }
}

test = new taskElementWork();
test.createBlockSaveNew();
```

Comment: Can you sort out your indentation.

Comment: Could it be an index issue? Maybe start with struct_one.comments[0].comment, then go to 1, then 2

Comment: Also `this` in `this.createBlockSaveNew` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: if  start with struct_one.comments[0].comment the result will be "String() { [native code] }"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the same object reference on pushing.

You could take a new object before assigning values and pushing, like

```
function taskElementWork() {
    var struct_two = { comment: '' };
    struct_two.comment = 1 + "RED";
    struct_one.comments.push(struct_two); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[1].comment); // = 1RED

    struct_two = { comment: '' };
    struct_two.comment = 2 + "RED";
    struct_one.comments.push(struct_two); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[2].comment); // = 2RED

    var struct_two = { comment: '' };
    struct_two.comment = 3 + "RED";
    struct_one.comments.push(struct_two); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[3].comment); // = 3RED
}
```

A slighy better way, is to use a function for building the structure and take a parameter for the comment:

```
function taskElementWork() {
    function buildStructure(comment) {
        return { comment: comment };
    }

    struct_one.comments.push(buildStructure(1 + "RED")); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[1].comment); // = 1RED

    struct_one.comments.push(buildStructure(2 + "RED")); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[2].comment); // = 2RED

    struct_one.comments.push(buildStructure(2 + "RED")); 
    console.log(struct_one.comments[3].comment); // = 3RED
}
```